# What is the difference between H.264 depay and H.264 parse in GStreamer world?

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, codec, gstreamer-1.0

I have a RTSP source. The data come in as stream of NAL units. I suppose that the RTP packets need to be "depay" or "parsed" into something that H.264 decoder can understand.

```
rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! ...
```

What's the actual difference between depay and parse? Intuitively it seems to me that they are doing the same thing. But Gstreamer pipeline won't work if I remove one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rtph264depay`: RTP -> H.264 bitstream

`h264parse`: H.264 bitsream -> bytestream or AVC samples and NAL or AU packing

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on when I should use one or the other? Does one of the two have advantages over the other? Thank you

Comment: They are doing completely different things.

Comment: I was suggested to use it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399469/gstreamer-corrupted-image-from-rtsp-video-stream?noredirect=1#comment126342977_71399469 between `rtph264depay` and `nvv4l2decoder` but it does not seem to make any difference (at least it does not solve my issue)