# Gstreamer corrupted image from rtsp video stream

Tags: image, video, gstreamer, pixel, rtsp

I am using an `rtpsrc` element to decode rtsp video streams. Since my pipeline is rather heavy and slow, I set the property `drop-on-latency` to `1` to avoid memory leak. Sometime I see some image pixelated / corrupted. Can this be the cause of such issue?

EDIT: you can reproduce the following code. In order to run the code, you need to:

- Add your rtsp video url at line 149
- On line 150 you can select how many decoding bin you want to create using the stream above. Set the number of streams to 64. With 64 streams, the memory leak is evident in a few seconds using utilities such as top and htop. With just 1 stream you won’t notice the memory leak.
- If you uncomment line 38-39 you will solve the memory leak, but this will lead to corrupted video frames when connecting this video decoding bin to an actual Deepstream pipeline (with nvinfer, etc)

NOTE: see updated code below

```
import time
import traceback

import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
gi.require_version("GstRtspServer", "1.0")
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstRtspServer

import gc
from threading import Thread
import pyds
import pygraphviz as pgv


NVV4L2DECODER_NUM_EXTRA_SURFACES = 1
NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS = 1



class RtspSourceBin:
    """ Class used to create a bin that decode an rtsp video stream.
    """

    @classmethod
    def create_rtsp_source_bin(cls, index: int, source_url: str, decoding_memory: str):
        # SOURCE BIN
        # Create a source GstBin to abstract this bin's content from the rest of the pipeline
        bin_name = "source-bin-%02d" % index
        rtsp_source_bin = Gst.Bin.new(bin_name)
        if not rtsp_source_bin:
            print(" Unable to create source bin \n")

        # INTERNAL BIN ELEMENTS
        rtspsrc = create_gst_elemement("rtspsrc", f"rtspsrc_{index}")
        rtspsrc.set_property("location", source_url)
        rtspsrc.set_property("protocols", "tcp")
        # Uncomment the following two lines to prevent the memory leak (but this will cause corrupted video frames)
        # rtspsrc.set_property("latency", 1000)
        # rtspsrc.set_property("drop-on-latency", 1)
        rtspsrc.set_property("timeout", 5000000)  # microseconds
        rtspsrc.set_property("debug", 1)

        rtph264depay = create_gst_elemement("rtph264depay", f"rtph264depay_{index}")

        if decoding_memory == "cpu":
            decoder, nvvideoconvert = cls._get_decoding_element_cpu(camera_index=index)
        elif decoding_memory == "cuda":
            decoder, nvvideoconvert = cls._get_decoding_element_cuda_device(camera_index=index)
        else:
            raise ValueError()

        # By converting images to RGBA we can download them from GPU whenever we want
        caps_filter = create_gst_elemement("capsfilter", f"filter_numpy_frame_{index}")
        caps_filter.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string((f"video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=RGBA")))

        # RTSPSRC GHOST PAD
        # rtspsrc will create a src pad once it starts decoding, for now we initialize a ghost pad
        # to be linked to next elment in the bin
        # We also add a callback on the signal "pad-added" to link the actual src pad when it is initialized
        rtspsrc.add_pad(
            Gst.GhostPad.new_no_target("src", Gst.PadDirection.SRC)
        )
        rtspsrc.connect("pad-added", cls.rtspsrc_callback_newpad, rtph264depay)

        # ADD ELEMENTS TO THE BIN
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, rtspsrc)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, rtph264depay)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, decoder)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, nvvideoconvert)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, caps_filter)

        # LINK ELEMENTS
        rtspsrc.link(rtph264depay)
        rtph264depay.link(decoder)
        decoder.link(nvvideoconvert)
        nvvideoconvert.link(caps_filter)

        # BIN GHOST PAD
        # We need to create a ghost pad for the rtsp source bin which will act as a src pad
        rtsp_source_bin.add_pad(
            Gst.GhostPad.new_no_target("src", Gst.PadDirection.SRC)
        )
        ghost_pad = rtsp_source_bin.get_static_pad("src")
        if not ghost_pad:
            print(" Failed to add ghost pad in source bin \n")
            return None
        ghost_pad.set_target(caps_filter.get_static_pad("src"))
        return rtsp_source_bin

    @staticmethod
    def _get_decoding_element_cuda_device(camera_index: int):
        nvv4l2decoder = create_gst_elemement("nvv4l2decoder", f"nvv4l2decoder_{camera_index}")
        nvv4l2decoder.set_property("cudadec-memtype", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_DEVICE))
        nvv4l2decoder.set_property("num-extra-surfaces", NVV4L2DECODER_NUM_EXTRA_SURFACES)
        nvvideoconvert = create_gst_elemement("nvvideoconvert", f"nvvideoconvert_{camera_index}")
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("nvbuf-memory-type", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_UNIFIED))
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("output-buffers", NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS)
        return nvv4l2decoder, nvvideoconvert

    @staticmethod
    def _get_decoding_element_cpu(camera_index: int):
        avdec_h264 = create_gst_elemement("avdec_h264", f"avdec_h264_{camera_index}")
        avdec_h264.set_property("output-corrupt", 0)
        nvvideoconvert = create_gst_elemement("nvvideoconvert", f"nvvideoconvert_{camera_index}")
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("nvbuf-memory-type", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_UNIFIED))
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("output-buffers", NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS)
        return avdec_h264, nvvideoconvert

    @classmethod
    def rtspsrc_callback_newpad(cls, rtsp_src, rtsp_src_new_src_pad, data):
        print(f"SourceBin: added pad {rtsp_src_new_src_pad.name} to {rtsp_src.name}")
        caps = rtsp_src_new_src_pad.get_current_caps()
        gststruct = caps.get_structure(0)
        # gstname = gststruct.get_name()
        # rtph264depay = data
        # features = caps.get_features(0)

        # Need to check if the pad created by the decodebin is for video and not audio.
        # TODO: are we checking if this is a video in the correct way?
        if gststruct.get_string("media") == "video":
            # Get the source bin ghost pad
            rtsp_src_ghost_pad = rtsp_src.get_static_pad("src")
            print(f"padcaps {rtsp_src_ghost_pad.get_current_caps()}")
            if not rtsp_src_ghost_pad.set_target(rtsp_src_new_src_pad):
                print(
                    "Failed to link decoder src pad to source bin ghost pad\n"
                )



def create_gst_elemement(factory_name, instance_name):
    element = Gst.ElementFactory.make(factory_name, instance_name)
    if not element:
        print(f" Unable to create {factory_name} {instance_name} \n")
    return element


# Standard GStreamer initialization
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

# Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
print("Creating Pipeline \n")
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
if not pipeline:
    print(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

# Url
rtsp_url = "... your rtsp url..."
number_of_streams = 1
for index in range(number_of_streams):
    # Create bin that decode the video stream
    rtsp_source_bin = RtspSourceBin.create_rtsp_source_bin(index=index, source_url=rtsp_url, decoding_memory="cuda")
    # Create leaky queue
    queue = create_gst_elemement("queue", f"queue_{index}")
    queue.set_property("leaky", 2)
    queue.set_property("max-size-buffers", 1)
    # Create fakesink
    fakesink = create_gst_elemement("fakesink", f"fakesink_{index}")
    fakesink.set_property("sync", 1)
    # Add elements to pipeline
    pipeline.add(rtsp_source_bin)
    pipeline.add(queue)
    pipeline.add(fakesink)
    # Link elements
    rtsp_source_bin.link(queue)
    queue.link(fakesink)

# create an event loop
loop = GObject.MainLoop()


# Start pipeline
print("Starting pipeline \n")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# Loop that calls the garbage collector so that we know the actual memory used
def _collect_garbage_loop():
    while True:
        try:
            gc.collect()
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            time.sleep(1)
thread_gc = Thread(target=_collect_garbage_loop)
thread_gc.start()

# Save graph
graph_data = Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_data(pipeline, Gst.DebugGraphDetails.ALL)
graph = pgv.AGraph()
graph.from_string(graph_data)
graph.layout("dot")
graph.draw("pipeline.pdf", format="pdf")
print("Graph saved")

# Run loop
try:
    loop.run()
except BaseException:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", str(e))

# cleanup
# pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

You can find the pipeline graph here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yGKMOswBQHCQx2333GlSrP7rxFctcnBZ/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: the following updated code with additional queue so that the code keeps decoding frames. As suggested I also added `h264parse`.
I still have the same issues.
Pipeline graph: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SS0z-xB2cCDw2m4aRj9IFaJ2WIPlboVW/view?usp=sharing

```
import time
import traceback

import cv2
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
gi.require_version("GstRtspServer", "1.0")
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstRtspServer

import gc
from threading import Thread
import pyds
import pygraphviz as pgv


NVV4L2DECODER_NUM_EXTRA_SURFACES = 1
NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS = 1



class RtspSourceBin:
    """ Class used to create a bin that decode an rtsp video stream.
    """

    @classmethod
    def create_rtsp_source_bin(cls, index: int, source_url: str, decoding_memory: str):
        # SOURCE BIN
        # Create a source GstBin to abstract this bin's content from the rest of the pipeline
        bin_name = "source-bin-%02d" % index
        rtsp_source_bin = Gst.Bin.new(bin_name)
        if not rtsp_source_bin:
            print(" Unable to create source bin \n")

        # INTERNAL BIN ELEMENTS
        rtspsrc = create_gst_elemement("rtspsrc", f"rtspsrc_{index}")
        rtspsrc.set_property("location", source_url)
        rtspsrc.set_property("protocols", "tcp")
        # Uncomment the following two lines to prevent the memory leak (but this will cause corrupted video frames)
        # rtspsrc.set_property("latency", 1000)
        # rtspsrc.set_property("drop-on-latency", 1)
        rtspsrc.set_property("timeout", 5000000)  # microseconds
        rtspsrc.set_property("debug", 1)

        rtph264depay = create_gst_elemement("rtph264depay", f"rtph264depay_{index}")

        h264parse = create_gst_elemement("h264parse", f"h264parse_{index}")

        if decoding_memory == "cpu":
            decoder, nvvideoconvert = cls._get_decoding_element_cpu(camera_index=index)
        elif decoding_memory == "cuda":
            decoder, nvvideoconvert = cls._get_decoding_element_cuda_device(camera_index=index)
        else:
            raise ValueError()

        # Video rate
        # videorate = create_gst_elemement("videorate", f"videorate_{index}")
        # videorate.set_property("drop-only", 1)
        # videorate.set_property("skip-to-first", 1)
        # videorate.set_property("max-rate", 1)

        # Queue to drop frames
        queue = create_gst_elemement("queue", f"queue_{index}")
        queue.set_property("leaky", 2)
        queue.set_property("max-size-buffers", 1)

        # By converting images to RGBA we can download them from GPU whenever we want
        caps_filter = create_gst_elemement("capsfilter", f"filter_numpy_frame_{index}")
        caps_filter.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string((f"video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=RGBA")))

        # RTSPSRC GHOST PAD
        # rtspsrc will create a src pad once it starts decoding, for now we initialize a ghost pad
        # to be linked to next elment in the bin
        # We also add a callback on the signal "pad-added" to link the actual src pad when it is initialized
        rtspsrc.add_pad(
            Gst.GhostPad.new_no_target("src", Gst.PadDirection.SRC)
        )
        rtspsrc.connect("pad-added", cls.rtspsrc_callback_newpad, rtph264depay)

        # ADD ELEMENTS TO THE BIN
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, rtspsrc)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, rtph264depay)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, h264parse)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, decoder)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, queue)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, nvvideoconvert)
        Gst.Bin.add(rtsp_source_bin, caps_filter)

        # LINK ELEMENTS
        rtspsrc.link(rtph264depay)
        rtph264depay.link(h264parse)
        h264parse.link(decoder)
        decoder.link(queue)
        queue.link(nvvideoconvert)
        nvvideoconvert.link(caps_filter)

        # BIN GHOST PAD
        # We need to create a ghost pad for the rtsp source bin which will act as a src pad
        rtsp_source_bin.add_pad(
            Gst.GhostPad.new_no_target("src", Gst.PadDirection.SRC)
        )
        ghost_pad = rtsp_source_bin.get_static_pad("src")
        if not ghost_pad:
            print(" Failed to add ghost pad in source bin \n")
            return None
        ghost_pad.set_target(caps_filter.get_static_pad("src"))
        return rtsp_source_bin

    @staticmethod
    def _get_decoding_element_cuda_device(camera_index: int):
        nvv4l2decoder = create_gst_elemement("nvv4l2decoder", f"nvv4l2decoder_{camera_index}")
        nvv4l2decoder.set_property("cudadec-memtype", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_DEVICE))
        nvv4l2decoder.set_property("num-extra-surfaces", NVV4L2DECODER_NUM_EXTRA_SURFACES)
        nvvideoconvert = create_gst_elemement("nvvideoconvert", f"nvvideoconvert_{camera_index}")
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("nvbuf-memory-type", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_UNIFIED))
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("output-buffers", NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS)
        return nvv4l2decoder, nvvideoconvert

    @staticmethod
    def _get_decoding_element_cpu(camera_index: int):
        avdec_h264 = create_gst_elemement("avdec_h264", f"avdec_h264_{camera_index}")
        avdec_h264.set_property("output-corrupt", 0)
        nvvideoconvert = create_gst_elemement("nvvideoconvert", f"nvvideoconvert_{camera_index}")
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("nvbuf-memory-type", int(pyds.NVBUF_MEM_CUDA_UNIFIED))
        nvvideoconvert.set_property("output-buffers", NVVIDEOCONVERT_OUTPUT_BUFFERS)
        return avdec_h264, nvvideoconvert

    @classmethod
    def rtspsrc_callback_newpad(cls, rtsp_src, rtsp_src_new_src_pad, data):
        print(f"SourceBin: added pad {rtsp_src_new_src_pad.name} to {rtsp_src.name}")
        caps = rtsp_src_new_src_pad.get_current_caps()
        gststruct = caps.get_structure(0)
        # gstname = gststruct.get_name()
        # rtph264depay = data
        # features = caps.get_features(0)

        # Need to check if the pad created by the decodebin is for video and not audio.
        # TODO: are we checking if this is a video in the correct way?
        if gststruct.get_string("media") == "video":
            # Get the source bin ghost pad
            rtsp_src_ghost_pad = rtsp_src.get_static_pad("src")
            print(f"padcaps {rtsp_src_ghost_pad.get_current_caps()}")
            if not rtsp_src_ghost_pad.set_target(rtsp_src_new_src_pad):
                print(
                    "Failed to link decoder src pad to source bin ghost pad\n"
                )



def create_gst_elemement(factory_name, instance_name):
    element = Gst.ElementFactory.make(factory_name, instance_name)
    if not element:
        print(f" Unable to create {factory_name} {instance_name} \n")
    return element


def print_resolution(rtsp_url):
    vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)
    status, frame = vcap.read()
    print("Frame shape", frame.shape)


# Standard GStreamer initialization
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

# Create Pipeline element that will form a connection of other elements
print("Creating Pipeline \n")
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
if not pipeline:
    print(" Unable to create Pipeline \n")

# Url
rtsp_url = "...rtsp url..."
number_of_streams = 64

print_resolution(rtsp_url)

for index in range(number_of_streams):
    # Create bin that decode the video stream
    rtsp_source_bin = RtspSourceBin.create_rtsp_source_bin(index=index, source_url=rtsp_url, decoding_memory="cuda")
    # Create fakesink
    fakesink = create_gst_elemement("fakesink", f"fakesink_{index}")
    fakesink.set_property("sync", 1)
    # Add elements to pipeline
    pipeline.add(rtsp_source_bin)
    pipeline.add(fakesink)
    # Link elements
    rtsp_source_bin.link(fakesink)

# create an event loop
loop = GObject.MainLoop()


# Start pipeline
print("Starting pipeline \n")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# Loop that calls the garbage collector so that we know the actual memory used
def _collect_garbage_loop():
    while True:
        try:
            gc.collect()
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            time.sleep(1)
thread_gc = Thread(target=_collect_garbage_loop)
thread_gc.start()

# Save graph
graph_data = Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_data(pipeline, Gst.DebugGraphDetails.ALL)
graph = pgv.AGraph()
graph.from_string(graph_data)
graph.layout("dot")
graph.draw("pipeline.pdf", format="pdf")
print("Graph saved")

# Run loop
try:
    loop.run()
except BaseException:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", str(e))

# cleanup
# pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Comment: Yes and No also package loss can result in Image artifacts, you can try using queues or Look deeper where this happen, Just reduce pipline Elements and look into the result

Comment: The problem is that I set `drop-on-latency` because otherwise there is a memory leak in my pipeline. I se tried to add a queue after the decoder a `queue` with `leaky=2` and `max-size=1` with the goal of dropping frames in excess but it still results in a memory leak

Comment: Hmm why do you have memory leaks that sounds strange, could u post your pipeline? Wich version of gstreamer u use ?

Comment: Hello @Christoph , I just edited the post above with some reproducible code and and pipeline graph. Using Gstreamer 1.14.5 in the Deepstream 6.0 devel container.

Comment: Do you have also artifacts/pixelate images If you have Just one stream with drop on latency and latency settings on?

Comment: Here are two images https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g3KlRfy-ktAsZrak27QJgBAwLPzNGZDN/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbYG1_ioxoesivxNwXg39MjkI-inpApl/view?usp=sharing ? I can't share the rtsp video url because of privacy reason. Are the images enough?

Comment: There u have just one stream at time right? Could u try UDP as Transport?

Comment: The memory leak is fairly evident if you set 60 streams in the Python script. You can use the same url to do that. I am not totally sure if the memory leak is present with 1 stream (I suppose so) just because `htop` shows only Gigabytes used (and hundreds of megabytes used) but I can check

Comment: If I try UDP nothing happens but I suspect the code is not actually decoding any video. If I add other components to the pipeline, it seems it can't actually decode the video using UDP because it gives the following error `No supported stream was found. You might need to allow more transport protocols or may otherwise be missing the right GStreamer RTSP extension plugin. (6): gstrtspsrc.c(7052): gst_rtspsrc_setup_streams_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:source-bin-00/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc_00`

Comment: This might be caused by the `fakesink` not playing in my script above. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @Christoph you are my only chance to solve this. I would appreciate any hint even minimal :) Thank you!

Comment: Hey, looks UDP is not supported, wich rtsp source you use, are you sure that this source can u provide so much streams at once? Try to remove drop-on-latency, timeout and latency property settings, then start with one stream and look if the run smootly when yes slightly increase the streams and proof when artifacts are happen. When this just happen with one stream check your stream with ffplay and check if you loose rtp packages what can be an indicator for bad Network conditions. Also you could at the end To-Do a update of gstreamer to latest version.

Comment: You forgot to h264parse between the rtpdepay and the nv4l2. rtph264depay produces a stream, and you want it to be segmented and parsed before it moves on

Comment: Hi @Carson, what will  `h264parse` do? I am going to try it. 
@Christoph apparently the memory leak is caused by the huge amount of data that I am trying to decode with NVDEC. NVDEC can't keep up, and therefore the buffer gets accumulated. But if I set `drop-on-latency` the images will be pixelated. Not sure there's really a solution here

Comment: @Carson I added the `h264parse` but I still get pixelated images if I enable `drop-on-latency`.